# Throwing exception when creating dropdown validation in vba

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub Example(x As Range, y As Range)

  With y.Validation
      .Delete
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=x.Value
      .IgnoreBlank = True
      .InCellDropdown = True
      .InputTitle = ""
      .ErrorTitle = ""
      .InputMessage = ""
      .ErrorMessage = ""
      .ShowInput = True
      .ShowError = True
  End With
End Sub
```

This is the function i am using for creating dropdown list from comma separted cell. But its throwing exception in the line of
  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=x.Value

The Error is :

> 1004- Application-defined error

Here is the code for looping:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
  Range("D2").Select

  Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("FacT&C")

  Dim LastRow As Long 'always use long instead of integer
  LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

  Dim iRow As Long
   For iRow = 2 To LastRow
     Example ws.Cells(iRow, "AD"), ws.Cells(iRow, "R")
   Next iRow
End Sub
```

Pls help me out

Comment: I fixed that error now. But the problem is first time its working as expected. but when I close and open the workbook,its repairing the sheet and its not populating the data. I have cross verfied that is happening because of this set of code.

Comment: You should provide an `Operator`, too. And `Formula1` should look like `"=$A$2:$A$5"`. Note the `=` sign.

Comment: im doing loop till the lastrow. Also at very first time, the dropdown is coming with values. but second time if i open the same excel, its corrupted.

Comment: I tried with ur formula. Its not splitting the comma separated value. its taking all the values with (,) into the dropdown

Comment: You should submit a new Question for your new question.

Comment: ok let me do it